# Ajax call always fires error function call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am looking to post the data using an ajax call from MVC to Post API. The data is successfully posted, but the ajax call always fires the error function alert.

**View Page**

```
<div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmVisitID, new { Class = "form-control input-circle-right", @readonly = "readonly", @id = "Cvid" })
</div> 
 //all the input fields comes here
 <input value="Confirm" type="button" id="loccat" onclick="CheckPromotionalCode();">
```

**Script**

```
  <script>
    function CheckPromotionalCode() {
    var jva = document.getElementById('Mid').value;
    var cid = document.getElementById('Cvid').value;
    var pname = document.getElementById('PatientName').value;
    var datefrom = document.getElementById('SDate').value;
    var dateend = document.getElementById('EDate').value;
    var mc = document.getElementById('IsMC').value;
    var dept = document.getElementById('IsDepartment').value;
    var empl = document.getElementById('IsEmployee').value;
    var depen = document.getElementById('IsDependent').value;
    var res = document.getElementById('reason').value;
    var remark = document.getElementById('rem').value;

    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:89522/Mc/McIssued',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Mid: jva, Cvid: cid, PatientName: pname, SDate: datefrom, EDate: dateend, IsMC: mc, IsDepartment: dept, IsEmployee: empl, IsDependent: depen, reason: res, rem: remark }),
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',

        success: function (response) {               
            alert("Successfull");
            window.location.href = response.Url;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Not Successfull");
        }
    });      
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult McIssued(string Cvid, string Mid, string SDate, string EDate, string reason, string rem, string IsMC, string IsDepartment, string IsEmployee, string IsDependent, string PatientName)
    {
       string url = "http://localhost:74523";
                 System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();                     
                 McIssued mc = new McIssued()
                                             {
                                                 MemberID = Mid,
                                                 ConfirmVisitID = Cvid,
                                                 ProviderID = PID,
                                                 CreateUserID = UserId,
                                                 StartDate = StrtDate,
                                                 EndDate = EndDate,
                                                 McType = reason,
                                                 Remarks = rem,
                                                 RecStatus = Rec, 
                                                 ModifyUserID = ModifyUserId                                                   
                                                };

                 HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<McIssued>("api/Mc/InsertintoMcTxn", mc).Result;
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
                 response.ToString();
                 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("IssueMC", "Mc");
                 return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
    }
```

So, how can I overcome this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the page making the request isn't served from `http://localhost:89522`, the problem is probably that you're running into the Same Origin Policy. Surely there's some relevant information in the browser console and/or network tab?

Comment: Which error are you getting in your web console?